# C++: using namespace, global variable won't work

Tags: c++, scope, static, namespaces

I got the following problem:

When I use this code

```
#include <iostream>

int count = 10; /* Global variable */

int main() {
   while(count--) {

   }
   return 0;
}
```

the code compiles perfectly well. However, if I add "using namespace std;" then I get the error message "count undeclared" in the while-loop. The same is also true if I add "static" before "int count". I am new to C++ so I have not fully understood scopes etc. Can somebody explain? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/667974613315759d). Post a [MCVE] of the non working code please.

Comment: Could you please write in the `using namespace std;` statement into the code for everybody's reference. Also, what compiler are you working with? I was not able to reproduce it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b9ef25d202c5af9

Comment: The question shows code that **works** but should show the code that **doesn't work**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

name space `std` also declares name `count`. This name corresponds to the standard algorithm `std::count`.
So when you include the directive

```
using namespace std;
```

and when use unqualified name `count` like this

while(count--) {
       //...
   }

then there can be an ambiguity.

To resolve the ambiguity you should use a qualified name. For example

```
    using namespace std;

    //...

   while( ::count--) {
          ^^^^^^^^
       //...
   }
```

In general it is not a good idea to use the directive that can lead to such an ambiguity as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because the name 'count' has another definition in std llibrary.
look here - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count.

```
std::count
```

Count is a template definition that was definted in the standart library,  after using the `using namespace std` the compiler cant tell between the count varable and the count template from the std lib.
you might wanna change count integer name :)

Comment: Must be a compiler specific implementation problem (`algorithm` is included by `iostream`).

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why I didn't get to the answer by myself, since it is quite obvious. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confuse, simply use this
    ::count /* :: is a prefix operator used to call global variables */
use :: operator whenever you need to call a global variable.